# Поиск слова в файле и вывод строки содержащей слово

Tags: delphi, файлы

Всем, добрый день! Пишу программу, нужно выполнить поиск слова в файле и вывести строку с этим словом... Проблема в том как вывести эту строку...

Comment: А зачем Вы её пишите? grep или sed не могут выполнить эту работу?

Comment: Считываете из файла построчно, потом проверяете строку на наличие слова, если есть совпадения - выводите строку. Что вы сделали сами и что не получилось?

Comment: не  получается именно вывод... и ругается когда переменной присваиваю значение с эдита

Comment: Код, на который ругается, приведите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это все потому, что нужно в коде поменять эту фигню на эту фигню, и заработает точно!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Вывести строку**

Процедура [ShowMessage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Dialogs.ShowMessage) выводит простое диалоговое окно на экране с кнопкой ОК, содержащее строку.

```
begin
  // Показ простого сообщения
  ShowMessage('Hello World');
end;
```

**2. ругается когда переменной присваиваю значение с эдита**

Осмелюсь предположить, что "ругается" на несоответствие типов.

---

*Покажите Ваш код. В вопросе ни о каком эдите речи не идет.*
*Учитесь излагать мысли. Если вас не могут понять программисты, то как вас поймет компьютер?*